# Finding a 95% confidence interval for the difference between two beta values given some r output

Tags: regression, confidence-interval

The r output I would get is just the summary of a fitted model. For example:

```
fitmodel = lm(formula = response ~ predictor1 + predictor2)
summary(fitmodel)
```

I would also be given the $t_{0.25}$ value.

In particular I need to find (by hand) a 95% confidence interval for the difference between beta1 and beta2, which are coefficients for predictor1 and predictor2, respectively.

I'm guessing the formula is something like:

$beta1 - beta2 \ \ \pm \ \ t_{0.25}SE$

where $SE$ is the standard error for $beta1 - beta2$. I also don't know how to find the $SE$ for this case. However, I do know that the standard error for each coefficient is given in the next column in the summary output.

Comment: You need the sampling covariance of the estimates as well as their sampling variances.

Comment: @mdewey Are those not possible to find by hand from the output?

Comment: @sucksatmath not from any usual output, as most such output does not display sampling covariances. That *could* be omitted if one knew that predictor1 and predictor2 are independent...

Comment: @AdamO. So if  they are  indeed independent, then what?

Comment: @sucksatmath note: `var(x-y) = var(x) + var(y) - 2 cov(x,y)`. Independence means `cov(x,y)` is (about) 0. So you add the squared SEs from model output, square-root it, and that's the SE of the difference.